# Como aplicar un destroy() a una ventana Top Level?

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Quiero hacer que mi ventana top level cierre al momento de presionar el boton "Cerrar"que se ubica dentro la propia top level. Me podrian indicar que esta fallando?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 def win2 ():
  t1 = Toplevel(bg="Brown")
  t1.title("Modificar Datos")
  t1.geometry('500x300')
  t1.focus_set()
  t1.grab_set()
  t1.transient(master=ventana)



  inf=StringVar()
  t2=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf)
  t2.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=20)

  t2l = Label(t1,text='Ingrese dato',bg="Cyan2")
  t2l.grid(row=4, column=1,padx=100,pady=10, sticky = N)

  wb = Frame(t1, width = 15, height = 10)
  b1 = Button(wb, text = "Cerrar", bg = "SkyBlue", command = salir2)
  b1.pack()
  wb.grid(column = 1, row = 6)
```

Esta funcion crea la ventana toplevel junto con una label, un entry y un boton, el boton manda a llamar a la siguiente funcion:

```
def salir2():
  t1.destroy()
```

Segun yo la instancia correcta es t1 por ser la toplevel pero al correrlo me dice que t1 no esta definida.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\efrias002\Desktop\Python\SQL Tkinter v2.py", line 139, in  salir2
t1.destroy()
NameError: global name 't1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t1` no está definida porque es una variable local que solo existe dentro de tu función `win2`, por lo tanto `salir2` no puede acceder a ella.

Lo más simple en tu caso es que pases `t1.destroy` como callback directamente:

```
b1 = Button(wb, text="Cerrar", bg="SkyBlue", command=t1.destroy)
```

Hay otras posibilidades aunque no tienen mucho sentido solo para esto, como hacer que `t1` sea una variable global:

```
from Tkinter import *

def win2():
    global t1
    t1 = Toplevel(bg="Brown")
    t1.title("Modificar Datos")
    t1.geometry('500x300')
    t1.focus_set()
    t1.grab_set()
    t1.transient(master=ventana)

    inf = StringVar()
    t2 = Entry(t1, textvariable=inf)
    t2.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=20)

    t2l = Label(t1,text='Ingrese dato', bg="Cyan2")
    t2l.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=100, pady=10, sticky=N)

    wb = Frame(t1, width=15, height=10)
    b1 = Button(wb, text="Cerrar", bg="SkyBlue", command=salir2)
    b1.pack()
    wb.grid(column=1, row=6)


def salir2():
    t1.destroy()

ventana = Tk()
t1 = None
Button(ventana, text="Abrir TopLevel", command=win2).pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

o definir `salir2` dentro de `win2`:

```
def win2():

    def salir2():
        t1.destroy()

    t1 = Toplevel(bg="Brown")
    t1.title("Modificar Datos")
    t1.geometry('500x300')
    t1.focus_set()
    t1.grab_set()
    t1.transient(master=ventana)

    inf = StringVar()
    t2 = Entry(t1, textvariable=inf)
    t2.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=20)

    t2l = Label(t1,text='Ingrese dato', bg="Cyan2")
    t2l.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=100, pady=10, sticky=N)

    wb = Frame(t1, width=15, height=10)
    b1 = Button(wb, text="Cerrar", bg="SkyBlue", command=salir2)
    b1.pack()
    wb.grid(column=1, row=6)
```

Si tu app es medianamente compleja, considera usar programación orientada a objetos, te facilitará mucho la vida.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque estás definiendo la variable dentro de una función, y las demás funciones no la detectan por esto mismo